# Symfony command on controller generates "Maximum execution time"

Tags: php, symfony, console

I used this snippet in my controller

```
$app = new Application($this->container->get('kernel'));

$input = new StringInput('generate:doctrine:entity --no-interaction --entity=ModelBundle:MyTest --fields="title:string(100)"');
$output = new StreamOutput(fopen('php://temp', 'w'));

$app->doRun($input, $output);
```

It triggered the error "Error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded", I increased the Maximum execution time to 100, and still got the same error.

I tried the same command in CLI and worked nice.

I replaced in my controller the command generate:doctrine:entity by container:debug and I didn't get the error "Maximum execution time".

```
$input = new StringInput('container:debug');
```

I am using Symfony 2.6.1

Any hint ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the command you are calling requires some user input.

Not sure what you want to do but have you tried a simple exec() or passthru() call?